# USB GPS dongle doesn't return consecutive GSP traces

Tags: python, usb, sensor, gps

I used [this](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32868013468.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.5bf9b90aoYp4ZG) USB GPS dongle to retrieve GPS traces of user's trip. Device configuration is successful.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cgps -s
┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐┌──────────────────Seen 17/Used  7┐
│ Time:        2022-01-19T20:12:59.000Z (18)││GNSS   PRN  Elev   Azim   SNR Use│
│ Latitude:         11.66971820 N           ││GP 10   10  56.0  139.0  43.0  Y │
│ Longitude:         8.26336710 E           ││GP 16   16  31.0  334.0  22.0  Y │
│ Alt (HAE, MSL):   1333.127,   1257.352 ft ││GP 18   18  28.0   26.0  20.0  Y │
│ Speed:             0.06 mph               ││GP 23   23  49.0   80.0  30.0  Y │
│ Track (true, var):     0.0,  -0.0     deg ││GP 27   27  17.0  312.0  19.0  Y │
│ Climb:             0.20 ft/min            ││GP 31   31  42.0  210.0  26.0  Y │
│ Status:         3D DGPS FIX (19 secs)     ││SB127   40  35.0  101.0  34.0  Y │
│ Long Err  (XDOP, EPX):  0.86, +/- 10.6 ft ││GP 21   21   5.0  237.0   0.0  N │
│ Lat Err   (YDOP, EPY):  1.04, +/- 12.8 ft ││GP 25   25  17.0  134.0  16.0  N │
│ Alt Err   (VDOP, EPV):  3.83, +/-  843 ft ││GP 26   26  67.0  350.0  17.0  N │
│ 2D Err    (HDOP, CEP):  1.34, +/-  103 ft ││GP 29   29   7.0   71.0  25.0  N │
│ 3D Err    (PDOP, SEP):  4.06, +/-  288 ft ││GP 32   32  10.0  173.0  22.0  N │
│ Time Err  (TDOP):       2.34              ││SB124   37  69.0  131.0   0.0  N │
│ Geo Err   (GDOP):       4.69              ││SB126   39  66.0  124.0  32.0  N │
│ Speed Err (EPS):       +/-  1.4 mph       ││QZ  1  193   n/a    0.0   0.0  N │
│ Track Err (EPD):        n/a               ││QZ  2  194   n/a    0.0   0.0  N │
│ Time offset:            0.105887000 s     ││QZ  4  196   n/a    0.0   0.0  N │
│ Grid Square:            JK41dq10          ││                                 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

But the GPS values don't change even as I move. It seems the device keeps the first value received all the time.

My Code:

```py
import time
import gpsd

def get_location():
   gpsd.connect()
   packet = gpsd.get_current()
   lat, lon = packet.position()

   return lat, lon

while True:
    lat, lon = get_location()
    print(f'Lat: {lat} Long: {lon}')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
Lat: 11.6697182 Long: 8.2633671
Lat: 11.6697182 Long: 8.2633671
Lat: 11.6697182 Long: 8.2633671
Lat: 11.6697182 Long: 8.2633671
Lat: 11.6697182 Long: 8.2633671
Lat: 11.6697182 Long: 8.2633671
...
```

**EDIT**

moved `gpsd.connect()` to top of script, comment-out `time.sleep(1)` to read data fast as suggested in comment. No change in GPS when moved around.

```
import time
import gpsd

gpsd.connect()

def get_location():
    packet = gpsd.get_current()
    lat, lon = packet.position()
    time = packet.time

    return lat, lon, time # to check _time received

while True:
    lat, lon, time_received = get_location()
    print(f'Lat: {lat} Long: {lon} received at {time_received}')
    #time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:54.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
Lat: 11.6644024 Long: 8.265238 received at 2022-01-20T21:03:55.000Z
```

**EDIT-2**

Following CoderMike answer, I proceeded to check with my device as follows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg
[    4.684442] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    4.764797] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[    4.764842] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.764864] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Serial
[    5.060743] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    5.212089] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271, bcdDevice= 1.08
[    5.212134] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[    5.212157] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
[    5.212176] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[    5.212193] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 12345
[    5.510653] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[    5.643658] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=01a7, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    5.643700] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.643721] usb 1-1.4: Product: u-blox 7 - GPS/GNSS Receiver
[    5.643741] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com
[    6.052589] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: no DMA platform data
.
.
.
[   23.598475] vc4_hdmi 20902000.hdmi: Could not register sound card: -517
[   24.890816] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[   26.689587] cdc_acm 1-1.4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[   26.731357] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
```

I can confirm `gpsd, gpsd-clients,` and `gpsd-py3` all installed.

Starting up `gpsd`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl stop gpsd
Warning: Stopping gpsd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  gpsd.socket
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo gpsd /dev/ttyACM0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Then run my code above but the gps didn't change.

2. Using `pynmea2` encountered `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
import time, serial, pynmea2

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baud = 9600
serialPort = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = baud, timeout = 0.5)

while True:
    str = serialPort.readline().decode().strip()
    print(str)
    if str.find('GGA') > 0:
        msg = pynmea2.parse(str)
        print('Timestamp: %s -- Lat: %s %s Lon: %s %s -- Altittude: %s %s -- Satellites: %s' % (msg.timestamp, msg.lat, msg.lat_dir, msg.lon, msg.lon_dir, msg.altitude, msg.altitude_units,msg.sats))
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python my_location.py
$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50
$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW  UBX-G70xx   00070000 FF7FFFFFo*69
$GPTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 1.00 (59842) Jun 27 2012 17:43:52*59
$GPTXT,01,01,02,PROTVER 14.00*1E
$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSUPERV=AC SD PDoS SR*20
$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=OK*3B
$GPTXT,01,01,02,LLC FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFD*2C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/my_location.py", line 8, in <module>
    str = serialPort.readline().decode().strip()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

It seems the device isn't using `UTF-8` encoding:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gpsmon
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
tcp://localhost:2947          JSON slave driver>
(82) {"class":"VERSION","release":"3.22","rev":"3.22","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":14}
(301) {"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyACM0","driver":"u-blox","subtype":"SW 1.00 (59842),HW 00070000","subtype1":"PROTVER 14.00,GPS;SBAS;GLO;QZSS"
,"activated":"2022-01-27T19:56:21.856Z","flags":1,"native":1,"bps":9600,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00,"mincycle":0.02}]}
(122) {"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":false,"nmea":false,"raw":2,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":true}
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gpsmon
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
tcp://localhost:2947          JSON slave driver>
(82) {"class":"VERSION","release":"3.22","rev":"3.22","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":14}
(301) {"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyACM0","driver":"u-blox","subtype":"SW 1.00 (59842),HW 00070000","subtype1":"PROTVER 14.00,GPS;SBAS;GLO;QZSS"
,"activated":"2022-01-27T19:56:34.845Z","flags":1,"native":1,"bps":9600,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00,"mincycle":0.02}]}
(122) {"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":false,"nmea":false,"raw":2,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":true}
/dev/ttyACM0                  u-blox>
┌──────────────────────────┐┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ or":14}
│Ch PRN  Az  El S/N Flag U ││ECEF Pos: +6182815.42m +898051.03m +1281690.83m  │ ver":"u-blox","subtype":"SW 1.00 (59842),HW 00070000","subtype1":"PROTVER 14.00,GPS;SBAS;GLO;QZSS"
│ 0  10 126  61  32 070d Y ││ECEF Vel:     -0.06m/s     +0.02m/s     -0.02m/s │ :"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00,"mincycle":0.02}]}
│ 1  16 335  38  31 070d Y ││                                                 │ false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":true}
│ 2  18  29  21  29 040d Y ││LTP Pos:  11.669152695°   8.264389309°   538.71m │
│ 3  21 243  10  25 0304   ││LTP Vel:    0.00m/s   0.0°   0.00m/s             │
│ 4  22 186   9  11 040d Y ││                                                 │
│ 5  23  68  47  21 040d Y ││Time: 4 19:57:05.00                              │
│ 6  25 138  12  17 040d Y ││Time GPS: 2194+417425.000     Day: 4             │
│ 7  26 353  76  22 040d Y ││                                                 │
│ 8  27 319  19  32 070d Y ││Est Pos Err   9.85m Est Vel Err   0.00m/s        │
│ 9  29  78   5  12 040d Y ││PRNs: 10 PDOP:  1.4 Fix 0x03 Flags 0xdd          │
│10  31 204  36  39 070d Y │└─────────────────── NAV_SOL ─────────────────────┘
│11  32 167  12   0 010c   │┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│12 120 245  59   0 0110   ││DOP [H]  0.8 [V]  1.1 [P]  1.4 [T]  0.7 [G]  1.5 │
│13 124 131  69   0 0110   │└─────────────────── NAV_DOP ─────────────────────┘
│14 126 124  66   0 0110   │┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│15 194   0 -91   0 0110   ││TOFF: -0.126272301       PPS:      N/A           │
└────── NAV_SVINFO ────────┘└─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(26) b56201041200c856e118ae009d004b007e005e0035004d002270
(24) b56201201000c856e11814380300920812070f00000059ad
(60) b56201063400b05ae118b1300300920803dd5c3ada242b515a0586b4a307db030000000000000000000001000000190000008b00020a84d30100d620
(232) b5620130e000b05ae11812030000030a0d07203d7e00dcffffff09100d071f264f01ab01000005120d071e151d000c02000011150403190af300000000000d160d040b09ba00dffbffff02170d04152f44004afeffff
08190d04130c8a0096feffff001a0d04164c610149ffffff0a1b0d0720133f0179ffffff0c1d0d040c054e001af9ffff011f0d072824cc00040000000b200c03120ca70064f9ffff07781001003bf50000000000047c100100
45830000000000067e100100427c000000000010c1100100a50000000000000fc4100100a50000000000000ec5100100a5000000000000276f
(26) b56201041200b05ae1189a008b0042006f00530033004100b7e0
(24) b56201201000b05ae118b1300300920812070f000000da6d
```

Not sure why this device behaves different from most answers I read.

Comment: What happens if you move 'gpsd.connect()' to the start of your code?

Comment: Oh - are you reading too slowly - data is serial - read as fast as you can. Remove your time.sleep(1).

Comment: @CoderMike gpsd.connect() moved to top, time.sleep(1) commented out (as in eidt), no change.

Comment: What command are you using to point gpsd to your gps?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, but I simply installed gpsd-py3 and import the library in python as in the code.

Comment: You must start gpsd somehow and reference your USB GPS. I used the following and got my GPS on ttyACM0 working with gpsd and your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758488/cgps-and-gpsmon-delivering-different-values

Answer (score 1):

I got your code working with my USB GPS using the following:

dmesg shows my USB GPS connected on ttyACM0:

```
[557325.587821] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=01a8, bcdDevice= 3.01
[557325.587827] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[557325.587833] usb 1-1.3: Product: u-blox GNSS receiver
[557325.587838] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com
[557325.590493] cdc_acm 1-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Install gpsd, clients and python library:

```
sudo apt install gpsd,gpsd-clients
pip3 install gpsd-py3
```

Start gpsd:

```
sudo systemctl stop gpsd
sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyACM0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Results from your code:

```
Lat: 54.2622055 Long: -3.142765667 received at 2022-01-20T22:08:57.000Z
Lat: 54.262192 Long: -3.142775167 received at 2022-01-20T22:08:58.000Z
Lat: 54.2621855 Long: -3.142767833 received at 2022-01-20T22:08:59.000Z
Lat: 54.2621855 Long: -3.1427735 received at 2022-01-20T22:09:00.000Z
Lat: 54.262178167 Long: -3.142792667 received at 2022-01-20T22:09:01.000Z
Lat: 54.262181833 Long: -3.142791167 received at 2022-01-20T22:09:02.000Z
```

Personally I prefer using the serial and pynmea2 libraries to read GPS data:

```
import serial,time,pynmea2

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baud = 9600

serialPort = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = baud, timeout = 0.5)
while True:
    str = serialPort.readline().decode().strip()
    #print(str)
    if str.find('GGA') > 0:
        msg = pynmea2.parse(str)
        print("  Timestamp: %s -- Lat: %s -- Lon: %s -- Altitude: %s %s -- Satellites: %s" % (msg.timestamp,round(msg.latitude,6),round(msg.longitude,6),msg.altitude,msg.altitude_units,msg.num_sats))
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Output:

```
  Timestamp: 11:33:46 -- Lat: 54.262155 -- Lon: -3.142469 -- Altitude: 136.3 M -- Satellites: 03
  Timestamp: 11:33:47 -- Lat: 54.262143 -- Lon: -3.142469 -- Altitude: 136.3 M -- Satellites: 03
  Timestamp: 11:33:48 -- Lat: 54.262169 -- Lon: -3.142494 -- Altitude: 136.3 M -- Satellites: 04
  Timestamp: 11:33:49 -- Lat: 54.262149 -- Lon: -3.14249 -- Altitude: 136.0 M -- Satellites: 04
  Timestamp: 11:33:50 -- Lat: 54.262141 -- Lon: -3.142446 -- Altitude: 136.0 M -- Satellites: 04
  Timestamp: 11:33:51 -- Lat: 54.262139 -- Lon: -3.142444 -- Altitude: 136.0 M -- Satellites: 04
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I would have to admit the problem is with my device. I followed all steps in your answer correctly, yet no change in gps.

Comment: How log have you left the gps running for - it can take 15 minutes or so for my GPS to pick up satellites positioned on a window sill. You should run my code with python3 ('python3 my_location.py').

Comment: So this device is not suitable for mobile application where user's gps traces is required as he moves if it could take up to 10mins to read current location...?

Comment: I don't know about your device, I'm sure mine would be quicker outside in the open, its just the initial receiving of data, its quick once it starts receiving. I have another GPS that connects quickly but cost a lot more money.